# Large number of apache virtualhosts: Python mod_wsgi vs PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, python, mod-wsgi

I have a large number of low-traffic sites I'd like to host on the same Apache server, as many as 500 sites. Currently, I'm powering the pages with PHP and I have a different virtualhost set up for each site.

I'd like to migrate my sites to Django (there is a built-in multisites feature), and similarly, each site would need its own virtualhost. I see that I can do this with mod_wsgi.

Would there by any performance considerations if I had this many virtualhosts configured with mod_wsgi? I noticed there are mod_wsgi settings for threads and processes, and was concerned that mod_wsgi could consume resources differently than my current PHP-powered virtualhost configurations.

Comment: Is rewriting 500 sites from PHP to Python so easy today?

Comment: How are we supposed to know you "current PHP-powered virtualhost configurations"? There are a million ways to connect PHP to Apache, like mod_php, php-cgi, php-fcgi, php-fpm.

Comment: Wow! 500 on one server?